# Angular - mdDataTable pagination is not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using an angular library that's called [mdDataTable](https://github.com/iamisti/mdDataTable) to handle my tables with searching, paging and so on.
I am trying to reproduce the functionality from the "Ajax Search Support" demo on [this demo page](http://iamisti.github.io/mdDataTable/), but I can't get it to work. Searching works fine, but my paging will only show that one page is avalible even if the results is eleven items and my pageSize is set to 5 per page.

I'm not sure how to simulate an api-call on codepen so I'll paste the code.
I also depend on [Angular material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/) and [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource). $resource is my "dataService" and then I have a service called paginationHandler, that's really just picks up pagination information in the response headers from the server (Custom header) and stores it for the application to use. I got an interceptor that handles storing that data.

My view containing the table:

```
<md-card class="bg-white" layout-fill md-whiteframe="4db">
   <md-input-container class="padder-md m-t-xl">
       <label style="padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px;">Sök användare</label>
       <input type="text" ng-model="filterText">
   </md-input-container>
   <mdt-table paginated-rows="{isEnabled: true, rowsPerPageValues: [5,10,20,50,100]}"
              mdt-row-paginator="vm.paginatorCallback(page, pageSize)"
              sortable-columns="true"
              animate-sort-icon="true"
              mdt-row-paginator-no-results-message="Inga resultat hittades..."
              mdt-row-paginator-error-message="Fel uppstod vid hämtning av maskinmodeller."
              mdt-trigger-request="vm.getLoadResultsCallback(loadPageCallback)"
              mdt-row="{
                 'table-row-id-key': 'id',
                 'column-keys': [
                    'name',
                    'category',
                    'machineModelType.name',
                    'createdDate',
                    'remove'
                 ],
              }">
              <mdt-header-row>
              <mdt-column align-rule="left">Namn</mdt-column>
              <mdt-column align-rule="left">Kategori</mdt-column>
              <mdt-column align-rule="left">Typ</mdt-column>
              <mdt-column align-rule="left">Skapad</mdt-column>
              <mdt-column align-rule="left">Ta bort</mdt-column>
           </mdt-header-row>
        </mdt-table>
    </md-card>
```

And this is my controller. It's a route in ui-router that has the controller defined in that route "as vm", so I haven't forgotten to link the controller to the view.

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("app")
        .controller("detailsManufacturerCtrl", [
            "$stateParams",
            "dataService",
            "$scope",
            "paginationHandler",
            function ($stateParams, dataService, $scope, paginationHandler) {
                var vm = this;

        vm.machineModels = [];

                // Data retrieval


                vm.getMachineModels = function(){
                    dataService.manufacturerMachineModels.query({manufacturerId: $stateParams.id, sort: "name", page: 1, pageSize: 5, search: ""}, function(response){
                        vm.machineModels = response;
                        vm.pagination = paginationHandler.get();
                    });
                };


                // Machine Model Table Functions

                vm.paginatorCallback = function(page, pageSize){

                    var query = $scope.filterText ? $scope.filterText : '';

                    return uow.manufacturerMachineModels.query({
                        manufacturerId: $stateParams.id,
                        sort: "name",
                        page: page,
                        pageSize: pageSize,
                        search: query
                    }).$promise.then(function(result){
                        return {
                            results: result,
                            totalResultCount: result.length
                        }
                    });
                };

                var loadPageCallbackWithDebounce;

                $scope.$watch('filterText', function(){
                    if(loadPageCallbackWithDebounce){
                        loadPageCallbackWithDebounce();
                    }
                });

                vm.getLoadResultsCallback = function(loadPageCallback){
                    loadPageCallbackWithDebounce = _.debounce(loadPageCallback, 500);
                };


                // INIT
                vm.getMachineModels();
            }
        ])
}());
```

It's close to the demo except for the item properties and the dataservice is my own ofc.

This is where my ajax-call ends up. I use ASP.NET Web Api 2 as server.

```
[Route("", Name = "ManufacturerMachineModelList")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(int manufacturerId, // Url values
   // Filtering (None)
   string sort = "name", // Sorting
   int page = 1, int pageSize = 5, //Pagination
   string search = "") // Search
{
   try
   {
      var manufacturer = Uow.Manufacturer.GetById(manufacturerId);
      // Not Found
      if (manufacturer == null) { return NotFound(); }

      var machineModels = Uow.MachineModel.GetAll(sort, search)
          // Url filter
          .Where(mm => mm.ManufacturerId == manufacturerId)
          // Query filters (None)
          .ToList();


       // Pagination
       var paginationHeader = GetPaginationHeader(machineModels, pageSize, page, sort);
       HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add("Pagination", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paginationHeader));

       // Return list and add pagination
       return Ok(machineModels
          .Skip(pageSize * (page - 1))
          .Take(pageSize)
          .ToList());
   }
   catch (Exception exc)
   {
      return InternalServerError(exc);
   }
}
```

The "GetPaginationHeader()" method returns a anonymous object that looks like this:

```
var object = new 
{
   currentPage = page,
   pageSize = pageSize,
   totalCount = totalCount,
   totalPages = totalPages,
   previousPageLink = prevLink,
   nextPageLink = nextLink
}
```

Which I then add as a header that's exposed through CORS.
These values are always correct.
The thing is that I'm not really sure what to do with these values, if anything. At the moment I just store the values when the response that includes "Pagination" header comes back and nothing more.

When I make this call I get 11 results back, and the table shows the correct pageSize (5), but not the correct amount of pages (always 1, should be 3), so I only see the first five results.

So, finally, my question is, which values in the ajax search demo should I change to my own values? If none, what else am I doing wrong?

I'm totally stuck so any help is appriciated!

EDIT: I've been trying to get the demo working locally but without luck. If someone can help me get that to work, then I can debug the example and see where I go wrong.